# rand() doesn't obey srand() in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've written a program in Qt Creator 1.0.0 (Qt version 4.5.0) where at the beginning of main() function I've put

```
srand(time(0));
```

Then I'm calling rand() from another thread (subclass of QThread). In that function, rand() is producing same sequence of numbers each time I'm running the program.  I'm not running the program multiple times in a second.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to call srand in each thread, because the seed is stored in a thread-specific block.

Comment: This certainly may be the case. The standard does not guarantee it however, and I somewhat doubt that an implementation that didn't use a common seed would be standard conforming. Always ready to be corrected, however!